# Is the 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade safe for Windows dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, upgrade, windows-10

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed with Windows 10 dual boot. Should the 16.04 upgrade work without a problem on either OS?

Answer (score 2):

The fglrx proprietary AMD graphics drivers are no longer available in Ubuntu 16.04 and have been replaced by the open source radeon and amdgpu drivers. There have been issues with the some wireless adapters in Ubuntu 16.04.

The best way to check if everything works on your hardware in Ubuntu 16.04 is to download the Ubuntu 16.04 iso file from the official Ubuntu website and then make a bootable Ubuntu 16.04 live DVD/USB for testing Ubuntu 16.04. You can make a bootable Ubuntu 16.04 live USB using the built-in Startup Disk Creator application.

An Ubuntu iso is usually considered to have most of the bugs worked out after the first point release has been launched. Ubuntu 16.04.1 point release was released on July 16, 2016. An upgrade to a newer release is always accompanied by a larger element of risk than a fresh install, so you should backup your personal files before upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04.